# Have to check length and allow some special character in a textbox

Tags: javascript

Having a textbox have to check the length and I have to allow only some special charater

```
function checkPasswordLength(thisValue) {
    var regexp1 = new RegExp("(www|http|https|WWW|HTTP|HTTPS)");
    var regexp2 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%&*]$/i;
    if ((thisValue.length<8)||(!regexp2.test(thisValue.value))||regexp1.test(thisValue.value)) {
        modal({
            type: 'warning',
            title: 'Warning',
            text: 'Password must contain at least eight characters!!<br/>Special Character such as (:<>,.~`(){};/") are not allowed',
            center: false,
            callback: function () { $(thisValue).focus(); }
        });

        exit;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62cm88L9/4/).

Comment: what special characters you want to allow in text box. URL ' s ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to find urls you can use the reg exp

```
var urlRexp = /^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i
```

Also your code needs some changes

```
 if ((thisValue.length<8)|| ...
```

should change to

```
   if ((thisValue.value.length<8)||
```

In your JS FIddle donot load the code in OnLoad . Change it to 'No wrap - in ' option.

If you want to use your own Regular expressions you can checkout [RegExp101](https://regex101.com/) link to see how your code works. It an online regexp tester.

Hope this helps you.